# Does editing or comments on a question in itself cause it to be re-reviewed?

Tags: discussion, edits, reopen-closed

This text is part of the "this question is closed" banner:

> "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment."

Does editing a question, or leaving a comment, cause the question to be re-reviwed with a view to reopening, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2):

An edit to the question by the original poster will automatically place the question in the review queue. Directly from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) - **emphasis added**:

> Questions are marked [on hold] for the first five days after closure to encourage edits and improvements to the question. **If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked [on hold], it will automatically be placed in a review queue to be considered for reopening.**

Comment: There's some emphasis on the original poster making this edit - does that mean that a "helpful reviewer/editor" can't fix it up and cause this to happen?

Comment: An edit by anyone puts it back on the main page, where questions on hold or closed can be voted on for reopening by persons with that level of privilege.